# if td elem (.gridcell) has certain text (ie '...') alter its style on click

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

If specific `td` elem *i.e.* `.gridcell` contains certain text *ie* '`...`' within my date-`pageid="current_page"` I would like to create click function on such elements, which on click would remove my css `whitespace: nowrap` attribute and change it to `normal`. Below is what I have so far.... *(trying to do in ES6)*

```
 function removeWhitespace(event) { 
        const current = $('[data-pageid="current_page"] .gridcell');
            if ($('[data-pageid="current_page"] .gridcell:contains("...")').length > 0) {
              $(this).addEventListener('click', ()=>{ { 
                $(this).style.whiteSpace ='normal';

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, however, I suspect your "..." is a dynamic truncation of the text?

Notice how we apply the `CSS Selector` and then `filter`

```js
const check = () => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td[data-pageid="current_page"].gridcell'))
          .filter(el => el.innerHTML.indexOf('...') > 0)
          .forEach(el => {
                    el.classList.add('testClass');
                    el.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
                      alert(target);
                    });
                  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => check());
```

```css
.testClass {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td data-pageid="current_page" class="gridcell">Testing ...</td><tr>
  <tr><td>Testing ...</td><tr>  
</table>
```